# Tableau default device preview

Tags: tableau-api

How do you change the way a user opens a dashboard using Tableau Reader?

My current dashboard opens in Device Type 'Tablet' but none of my users will be using this as a device. I want the dashboard to open with another type, say 'Default'. Is this possible?

Comment: Oh - I've found out how. Dashboard > Device Layouts > Add Desktop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, as you have highlighted.

Dashboard >> Device Layouts > Add devices

[image]

You can also add the three devices and select the model within each device to optimise your view.

Device preview will give you this option

[image]

I'm sending you the below link in case you  want to read more on this interesting topic.

https://onlinehelp.tableau.com/current/pro/desktop/en-us/dashboards_dsd_create.html#Preview_and_add_a_device_layout

Hope you find this useful.

Comment: Thanks for the additional information. Very useful.

Answer (score 0):

1. Go to Dashboard.
2. Click on **Device Preview**. A toolbar appears on top.
3. Change the **Device Type** to **Default** using arrows given on side.

[image]